# Losing Context when Responding to Vue.js Event Bus by calling Local Method

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js, vuex

I'm having trouble with the syntax for capturing an event then calling a local method.  I've tried using arrow syntax, binding to 'this', and setting 'self' to 'this', but no matter what I do, I cannot invoke this.notify(...) from an event.  I get the error "this.notify is not a function." Which undoubtably means I can't cross some set of contexts?

The notify functionality works fine otherwise, in all sorts of conditions, EXCEPT when I try to invoke it from an event.

Nothing magic here. app.js loads bus(an event bus), vuex/store, and Notifications, then app.vue.

So I'm sending events thru the store, and in this case must get an unrelated component to call a mutation in the store, and the store then to run a function in another unrelated component that displays a notification.  Help appreciated. 
-Thanks.

App.js

```
(...)
    import Notifications from 'vue-notification';
    import velocity from 'velocity-animate';
    Vue.use(Notifications, { velocity });

    import app from "./app.vue";

    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        store,
        Notifications,
        app,
        render: h => h(app)
});
(...)
```

Component A - works just fine.

```
 (...) 
 <b-btn v-on:click="$parent.showPokeNotice('display this nonsense text')"> My Arbitrary Text </b-btn>
 (...)
```

Component B - but when I route thru the Store(Vuex) using an event, the context isn't the same.  And so the $notify() and this.notify() aren't available.

```
    <template>
         (...)
         <notifications 
             group="workspace" 
             position="top center" 
             width="40%">
         </notifications>
         (...)
    </template>

    (...)
    mounted: function() {
    (...)

        /* Register Listeners for the Notification alerts */
        var self = this;
        Bus.$on('showPokeNotice', function (noticeText) {
            self.showPokeNotice(noticeText);
        });
    },

    (...)
    methods: {
    (...)
        showPokeNotice : function (noticeText) {
            this.notify({... params ...}); <---THIS IS THE PROBLEM CONTEXT
        }
    (...)
    }
```

So, this.notify / ($notify) is within the Notifications component within Component B, but isnt' available from the event.

ERRORS:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "showPokeNotice": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'showPokeNotice' of undefined"
(found in <Root>)

TypeError: Cannot read property 'showPokeNotice' of undefined ...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your first call of Bus should use `self` instead of `this`. All of them should work, if `notify` is declared in `methods` along with `showPokeNotice`.

Comment: Sorry, typo. Yes.  But notify(), which is loaded in app.js, isn't accessible in the context.  I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

ANSWER

So, while in context of the component, we use

```
this.notify({...
```

But, when responding to events, we use:

```
this.$notify({...
```

So, apparently there is some scope (context) loss when using events to call globals.

I hope this provides value to someone else.....