# Javascript video onclick this.play is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm passing a reference to the video element into my javascript function but am getting the following error. What syntax should I use here?

HTML

```
        <video
          v-for="option in visualizerOptions"
          v-bind:key = "option.id"
          src="@/assets/testvideo.mp4"
          spinner-color="black"
          class="carousel__item"
          v-on:click="playVid(this)"
        />
```

Javascript

```
    playVid(this) {
      this.play()
    }
```

`Uncaught TypeError: this.play is not a function`

Comment: this is a reserved word, not to be used as functions parameter, probably.

Comment: It doesn't work if I use a different parameter word either :/

Comment: Why not try using `v-on:click="playVid"`?

Comment: It gives me the same error :/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue JS - Video processing with v-for play/pause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68084221/vue-js-video-processing-with-v-for-play-pause)

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49077687/1216281

Comment: `this.$play is not a function` :/

Comment: @MichaelMiller Can you please tell us what is `play` in your code base ? It is defined as a variable or method

Comment: @evolutionxbox This link is very helpful. I think using `$refs` is a better solution when paired with `v-for`

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I figured out the syntax on my own. Hopefully this helps others as I haven't seen this re-posted anywhere in my research.

The correct syntax to use here is `ele.target.play()`

```
    playVid(ele) {
      ele.target.play()
    }
```